Identify this post-catastrophic thriller, please?
I saw this on someone else's screen at the gym, and they were wearing headphones, so I couldn't hear any of the dialogue. I'm guessing it's in English because the signs were in English. All the characters I saw were white. It's set in the present-day, so it was likely released fairly recently, probably within the last 5 years, maybe 10 at a stretch.
The scenes I saw: A group of 2 men and 2 women go into a church. The men are in their late 20s, maybe early 30s. One has light brown hair, the other has dark brown hair. One woman looks a little older than the men, maybe mid-30s, and has dark brown wavy hair past her shoulder. The other woman is younger and has platinum blonde hair in a pixie cut. The group find a woman about their age who has long, wavy, dark blonde hair--I'm not sure if they were looking for her or just came across her. It's very dusty inside the church. As they leave the church, one of the guys steps in a pile of dust and disperses it--the long-haired blonde woman notices but none of the others do.
It's very dusty outside the church. Not a dust storm--just lots of dust and sand. The plants look like they're still alive, but barely.
The group take the long-haired woman to the hospital. By the time they get there, one of the men has her slung over his shoulder. They go inthrough the emergency entrance. Outside the door, there's a man strapped into a gurney, apparently dead. Lots of dead/unmoving people inside, but not quite everyone and no blood or obvious signs of disease. Looks like people may have just died where they were sitting/standing. No electricity but still lots of dust. 
At some point the place the long-haired woman on an examination table and I think go looking for supplies. At one point they look in the chaplain's office and he's sitting in his chair with his head back--likely dead. They keep going and see a large streak of blood on the wall of a hallway and the floor is littered with bodies but the bodies aren't bloody.
And then they changed the channel, so that's all I got. Anybody recognize it?

The Remaining (2014)

Possible duplicate but the new question is "better detailed".

The Remaining (2014)* seems a good fit and matches in pretty much all respects.
* Thanks to @pori for  the tip
.

A group of 2 men and 2 women go into a church. The men are in their late 20s, maybe early 30s. One has light brown hair, the other has dark brown hair. One woman looks a little older than the men, maybe mid-30s, and has dark brown wavy hair past her shoulder. The other woman is younger and has platinum blonde hair in a pixie cut.

Seems to be 5 people 


As they leave the church, one of the guys steps in a pile of dust and disperses it--the long-haired blonde woman notices but none of the others do.

In fact, it's the woman who kicks a bible turned to ashes.

The group take the long-haired woman to the hospital. By the time they get there, one of the men has her slung over his shoulder. They go in through the emergency entrance.
Yep...and they've added a girl with long dark hair at this point.


At some point the place the long-haired woman on an examination table and I think go looking for supplies. At one point they look in the chaplain's office and he's sitting in his chair with his head back--likely dead.

Bingo....this one's a little harder to make out though.


That's it exactly! Thanks!

Ah, so there were 3 generic white guys. 5 people go into the church, 6 come out...
